# Webcam in a JavaApplet

Tags: java, applet

I am trying to create a Java Applet that runs the client's webcam and take a picture with a button but I just couldn't find a way to run the webcam in an applet. Does anyone out there know a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that the Applet needs the hardware permission. Applets have a SecurityManager which reads policy-files from the Java-Installation. As standart the is no permission to read from external devices like WebCams or the filesystem.

For you problem I think, you should use the Applet as loader of a JFrame or something else, which runs the Application.

For the webcam you can use [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/), which is also avaiable for C++, Android and .NET.

Hope it helped you ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take a look on **[this example](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-applet)**. I suppose this is exactly what are you looking - how to create Applet using webcam capability and embed it on the HTML page. There is no problem with accessing hardware since JAR is signed with `jarsigner` tool. When JAR is signed with self-signed certificate, Java will ask user if he/she wants to run it. If it is signed with certificate from certification authority, it will not ask, just run it.

Demo applet is available here (be patient, webcam needs few seconds to initialize): http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/examples/applet

There are several frameworks you could use for this, such as:

1. [Webcam Capture](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture) which is simple Java library allowing you to read images from embedded or USB webcam, same as from IP / network cameras. It's not mature, but small and ready to be used in Applet. Example I provided above has been taken from it. You wouldn't have to code too much - almost everything is ready there. It works well on various systems, such as Windows, Linux and Mac OS.
2. [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) which is Java wrapper for OpenCV, but I do not recommend it, lack of documentation and ~100MB OpenCV installation package is too much for Java Applet. You could probably take only really required native binaries, but still it's very hard to distinguish which ones are really required. It defines huge API which is in my opinion very hard to learn.
3. [LTI-CIVIL](http://lti-civil.org/) which is a small framework allowing you to read images from embedded or USB connected webcam. It's very easy to use, but its not being maintained any more (last update in 2007).
4. [JMF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html) is Oracle media library for Java. It gives you an access to webcam and recording devices, however it is veeery old (last update in 2004) and not being maintained any more. It could be possibly used with Applet, but everyone who would like to use this applet have to install JMF on his / her PC. There are few installation packages - one for each supported system (Windows, Linux, Solaris, Mac OS).
5. [VLCj](http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/) which is Java wrapper for VLC player native binaries. It gives access to webcam, but is not able to detect it (at least on Windows), so you would always have to know webcam locator address (usually 0), to use it from Java Applet.
6. [OpenIMAJ](http://www.openimaj.org/) is quite powerful Java library for media analysis. It is very fast and portable, but unfortunately many 3rd party dependencies are required, so your Applet would have to download them all (at least 20MB if no more).

Therefore, if you decide to use option 1. it should be quite easy for you to redesign example I provided to fit your needs. In this example Maven is used, however the same effect can be achieved by using Ant or even by creating JAR manually.